# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0

Tags: ionic3

when i try to run ionic command (ionic cordova run android)
i get ...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
  >   Failed to download SHA1 for resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/grad
  >   le-3.0.0.pom'.
  >   For input string: "

Comment: It happened for me when prompting: ` ionic cordova emulate android ` .